# Create custom Gtk.Container

Tags: python-2.7, gtk3, box, pygobject

I've been trying to do create a custom container in PyGobject & Gtk3, but I have no idea on how to start...

My goal is to create a container able to "Ignore" size requisitions at developer's will.

For example, to host a single super-large label with a tickbox. If TRUE, expand the container to fulfill label's width request, so whole text is displayed. If FALSE, then keep actual size and ignore label's size requsitions, so container's size is always constant

But, as I've said before, I don't know how to start. I haven't found any source code or examples to look at.

At most, I found a "widget.py" example which shows a peek on how to write a custom widget, but what I'm looking for is "how to write a container", not a widget.

Do someone has some kind of example? Any Ideas?

PD: Also if someone knows where could I see the most inner source code of "How a Gtk.Box works" or "How does a Gtk.Box deals with size requisitions?", it could help too...

Comment: If they're going to have to set a flag, why don't they just use [`set_hexpand`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-hexpand) on the label?